# windows service does not

Tags: c#, excel, service

I have written a windows service that periodically calls an ExcelReader.exe( this exe reads data from an excel). Now the problem is that when i'm running ExcelReader.exe directly it is able to read data from excel but when i am calling it through windows service, i was able to call but ReadExcel was not performing full job. Since my service does not have any GUI and even ExcelReader.exe is console program do i need to enable service to "interact with desktop"

Here is my code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    AddToFile(path, "starting service");
    //set time interval for watch
    timer.Interval = 6 * 1000;
    timer.Enabled = true;
    // Add handler for Elapsed event
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    timer.Enabled = false;
    AddToFile(path, "stop service");
}

private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    AddToFile(path,"Add another entry");
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\ExcelReader.exe";
    p.Start();
}
```

Here is ExcelReader code:

```
namespace ExcelReader
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string path = @"D:\\Excel Reader log .txt";
        public static BindingList<myTeam> TeamList = new BindingList<myTeam>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            write(path, "console program");
            readexcel();
        }

        public static void readexcel()
        {
            MyExcel dailystatus = new MyExcel();
            IList<myTeam> datasource = (BindingList<myTeam>) TeamList;

            MyExcel.InitializeExcel();
            datasource = MyExcel.ReadMyExcel();

            foreach (myTeam member in datasource)
            {
                string memberdetails = member.Name + "  " + member.TaskPerformedToday + "  " + member.Progress;
                write(path, memberdetails);
                    //(path, memberdetails);
            }

            //CloseExcel();
        }

        public static void write(string path, string contents)
        {
            //set up a filestream
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            //set up a streamwriter for adding text
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            //find the end of the underlying filestream
            sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            //add the text 
            sw.WriteLine(contents);
            //add the text to the underlying filestream
            sw.Flush();
            //close the writer
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**output of ExcelReader.exe (when executed directly):**

console program
Name   Task Performed Today   Progress 
sanj    windows service        not completed
kumar   service                 completed

**output when service call the same function:**
starting service 
console program

so why is it that windows service is unable to perform all ExcelReader.exe instructions.

Comment: You do it wrong. If your code is used in different applications - move it to library. So create ExcelReader library, add reference to that library in your console app and service - use code without problems.

Comment: You've not shown us what `MyExcel` is, but if that's using office automation (as opposed to consuming the modern XML office formats directly) you should probably read [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757): "Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes i was using office automation....but is there any other way that i can read excel through windows service

Comment: @SnzivGupta - there are various suggestion in that article I linked to, it depends on what you're trying to do. They range from "use this alternative system instead" to "you're out of luck, try using a different data format", depending on what your goal is.